# Adding a new row before other records that have specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```
Id  | DateTime            | State
1   | 2018-07-16 10:00:00 | 0
2   | 2018-07-16 10:15:34 | 1
3   | 2018-07-16 10:21:12 | 0
4   | 2018-07-16 10:32:45 | 1
5   | 2018-07-16 10:44:05 | 0
```

I need a query (t-sql) that inserts a new row before each row that has State == 0. The new row should have DateTime = TheRowOfInterest(datetime) - 1 second and State = 1.

*TheRowOfInterest is every row that has State == 0.*

**Important constraint:** the new row should be added only if the previous record had State == 1.

The resulting table looks like this:

```
DateTime            | State
2018-07-16 10:00:00 | 0
2018-07-16 10:15:34 | 1
2018-07-16 10:21:11 | 1      <<<
2018-07-16 10:21:12 | 0
2018-07-16 10:32:45 | 1
2018-07-16 10:44:04 | 1      <<<
2018-07-16 10:44:05 | 0
```

I know I need to use window-ing functions but haven't got any far so any suggestions are welcome.

More info:

- The Id does not play any role in the resulting table
- **The Id may not be sequential**
- I'm using SQL Server 2014

Here are the Create statements and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SwitchSeries](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [State] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)
```

Filled with sample data:

```
INSERT INTO SwitchSeries VALUES
    (1, '2018-07-16 10:00:00', 0),
    (2, '2018-07-16 10:15:34', 1),
    (3, '2018-07-16 10:21:12', 0),
    (4, '2018-07-16 10:32:45', 1),
    (5, '2018-07-16 10:44:05', 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What is the need for this? Can't you just insert your rows normally and when you retrieve the data `ORDER BY [DateTime] ASC`? Also try not to give column names the same names as reserved words

Comment: @WhatsThePoint these series should be displayed in a linear chart (on/off over time). To form a rectangular like shapes I need a "1" datapoint just before the "0". The software accepts only t-sql queries. Thanks for pointing out reserved words.

Comment: Does it matter if the inserted row happens to have the same date/time as a row that is already in the table?

Comment: @HABO not sure show will the charting software react in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite a simple solution. You haven't posted what you've tried yet, which is really important when posting a question; it means the volunteers know you've put some effort in and you aren't expecting you to do their work for them.

Anyway, as I said, this was achieved with the use of a CTE, `LAG`, and  `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           LAG([State]) OVER (ORDER BY [datetime] ASC) AS PreviousState
    FROM dbo.SwitchSeries)
SELECT [DateTime], [State]
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,-1,[DateTime]), 1
FROM CTE
WHERE [State] = 0
  AND PreviousState = 1
ORDER BY [DateTime];
```

I, however, totally agree with WhatsThePoint's comment; don't use keywords as column names. Both `state` and `datetime` are keywords in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

if you know that identity values are sequential, then you can simply join the table with itself like this:

```
select DateAdd(ss, -1, s2.DateTime), 1
from SwitchSeries s1 inner join SwitchSeries s2 on s1.Id = s2.Id - 1
where s1.State = 1 and s2.State = 0;
```

you can also check the fiddle here

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99208/3)

Comment: Unfortunately IDs aren't sequential. I'll update the question.